# Set a variable in a class to be used on multiple functions/methods

Tags: php, class, oop

I am trying to set a variable of **$tester** that can be used in multiple functions in **MyClass**.

I have set the variable and added a function on `__construct()` but I am getting an undefined variable notice when I try to echo it out - why is this?

```
    class MyClass {

        public $tester;

        public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'variables' ) );
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'do_stuff' ) );
        }

        public function variables() {
            $tester = get_option( 'an_option' );
        }

        public function do_stuff() {
            echo $tester;
        }

    }

    $my_class   =   new MyClass();
```

Comment: `$this->tester`, not `$tester` - the former is the instance property; the latter is locally scoped to the method ([PHP Class Properties 101](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php))

Comment: Objects are assigned and passed as reference in PHP by default, no need for the `&` in your `&$this`

Comment: Can these be dupes?  One right after the other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621759/object-variable-remains-undefined-after-being-set-in-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass {

    public $tester;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'variables' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'do_stuff' ) );
    }

    public function variables() {
        $this->tester = get_option( 'an_option' );
    }

    public function do_stuff() {
        echo $this->tester;
    }

}

$my_class   =   new MyClass();
```

Try this. Properties in a class called always  with `$this->`.
Have a look on this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you wanted could you define the variable in anyway as $variable in the functions?

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge No, because then the variable scope is only in that local function, not in the class